# PHPMYADMIN function type

Tags: php, mysql

I am helping a friend of mine edit his PHP school management system

but his user table in PHPMYADMIN has a password field like this:

$2y$10$yfi5nUQGXUZtMdl27dWAyOd/jMOmATBpiUvJDmUu9hJ5Ro6BE5wsK

Does anyone know what function its using in the password field for this? I have tried HEX and MD5 but with no success.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encrypted password :$2y$10 and $2y$13](//stackoverflow.com/q/44220911)

Comment: is that application using Yii framework PHP

Answer (score 1):

Probably he using the built-in function [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).
If you want to verify the password with given string from some form that the user submit, you can use the built-in function [`verify_password()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if it helped you.